# Approximately when did the term "meme" reach the tipping point into widespread popularity on the internet?

Tags: meaning, etymology, internet

When you look up the etymology of the word "meme", you find a bunch of stuff talking about [its origins in Richard Dawkins's *The Selfish Gene*](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/557736-we-need-a-name-for-the-new-replicator-a-noun) of course, originally as a term to refer to an idea that can be replicated via transmission between brains with corruption along the way, in analogy to how genes are replicated and corrupted via DNA. You also quickly find [Godwin (of Godwin's Law fame) explaining the term and relating it to the internet in a 1994 Wired article](https://www.wired.com/1994/10/godwin-if-2/) (using something very close to its original meaning), and I've seen [some quotes from the mid-2000s as well](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meme#Noun); though I believe these might be still referring to memes in the strictly Dawkinsian sense.

But of course one of the modern senses of "meme" is something more like "a specific instance of internet culture that can is copied and spread (more or less) verbatim, often but not always based on a template". It is kind of easy to see how this meaning might have evolved, but my recollection is I don't really recall seeing the term "meme" online so much through the noughties, maybe until the later part of that decade. Certainly it could have been particular to the circles I was in, but instead there were terms to describe specific types of (what we would today call) meme like "image macros" or "lolcats", and more general terms like "internet phenomena" or "internet references", but not widespread use of "meme". I note that Know Your Meme was launched as a project in September 2007 — was the term already in widespread use this early or was Know Your Meme perhaps influential in spreading it as a term or increasing its applicability?

Comment: Please quote the sources where you looked up the etymology of this word. This will help anyone interested in your question to see the research you have already done. You might also provide some data regarding the popularity of this term on the internet. I personally read it more in print, but my usage of the internet likely differ from yours. Oh, and you might tell us what it is supposed to mean.

Comment: It could be worth your time looking up the term (and associated ones) on Google Trends and Google Ngrams and post the results here.

Comment: @David good idea, done :)

Comment: @dubious great idea, no idea why I didn't think of doing that. I blame the fact that I'm ill today. Will try that and maybe answer my own question if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a Google ngrams search, the term "internet meme" (thus attempting to normalise against Dawkinsian uses unrelated to internet culture) [seems to start picking up steam in about 2005 but growth really seems to pick up in 2009-2010](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=internet+meme&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) which certainly fits my own feelings on the matter.

[image: Google ngrams graph to show internet meme usage in books over time]

The trend on [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=internet%20meme) is substantially less clear to see, but it seems to indicate steady growth starting around 2008 and then with a rapid growth in late 2011 up to a peak in 2012, from which it dropped off. Again this fits with my personal experience more or less.

[image: Google Trends to show internet meme search activity over time]

Comment: I will not mark this answer accepted for the time being as it'd be cool to figure out if there was some inciting incident of a particular thing being widely called a meme that led to the term spreading, or otherwise a reason it spread at the time it did, but maybe that wasn't the case.

Comment: The thing is the word is used since people are still creating them. There is no other word for a square with a design and a comment underneath that is sent out or posted and then keeps circulating on the internet, right?

Comment: @Lambie as mentioned in my OP the old term for that particular type of meme was "image macro". And I never suggested the word should fall out of use!

Comment: I am just saying it is still very much in use, that's all.

Comment: The OED's first citation in the meaning "An image, video, piece of text, etc., typically humorous in nature, that is copied and spread rapidly by internet users, often with slight variations" is 1998, from Science and Technology Week in a transcript of a CNN broadcast: "The next thing you know, his friends have forwarded it on and it's become a net meme." This is discussing the [dancing baby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_baby), so that could be said to be the first thing to be called a meme, even though it clearly precedes the 2010-ish popularisation of the term.

Comment: @StuartF If they called that a meme, it seems like they were using it for what has come to be known as "viral" -- the dancing baby was a viral video. I think Internet meme has since developed a more narrow definition, typically a humorous or satirical template.

Comment: @Muzer I don't think it was as simple as one single event, it was more of a cumulative snowball effect over time. I think the concept of the meme evolved before, and then people started increasingly to apply the word meme to the concept. Its your classic example of the concept of descriptivism.